# when didselect the tableviewcell scroll the collectionviewcell

Tags: ios, swift

I have collectionviewcell.Inside the collectionviewcell i have used tableview.
When i select the cell from the tableview i need to scroll the collectionviewcell.I have used the collectionview horizontal.How to do?

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.mainquestionViewModel.numberOfSections()

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = verticalCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NH_MainHeader", for: indexPath)as!  NH_MainHeader

        cell.tableView.dataSource = self

        cellTypes = [.NHCheckBoxCell, .NHRadioTypeCell, .NHSmileyTypeCell, .NHStarRatingTypeCell, .NHTextTypeCell,.NHDatePickerTypeCell]

        for type in cellTypes{
            cell.tableView.registerNibForCellClass(type.cellType().getClass())
        }


        cell.setReviewData(reviews:self.mainquestionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.row))

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.mainquestionViewModel.numberOfRowsIn(section: section)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        let model = self.mainquestionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
        print(model.answerType)

        print(model.answerType?.rawValue)
        let c = model.answerType
        return c!.cellType().getHeight()
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let model = self.mainquestionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)

        print(model.options)

        print(model.answerType)

        print(model.answerType?.rawValue)

        let c = model.answerType
        let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
        print(cellClass)

        let optionModel = self.mainquestionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: (cellClass?.cellReuseIdentifier())!, for: indexPath) as! BaseCell


//      cell.setOptions(Options1:model.optionsModelArray[indexPath.section])

        cell.setOptions(Options1:self.mainquestionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
              return cell

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){


        let model = self.mainquestionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)

        print(model.options)

        print(model.answerType)

        print(model.answerType?.rawValue)

        let c = model.answerType
        let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
        print(cellClass)

        let optionModel = self.mainquestionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: (cellClass?.cellReuseIdentifier())!, for: indexPath) as! BaseCell




    }
```

How to scroll the collectionviewcell.While clicking the tableviewcell from the collectionviewcell in swift

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
  self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: //scroll collection view to indexpath
                              NSIndexPath.init(row:(self.collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: sectionNumber))!-1, //get last item of self collectionview (number of items -1)
                                               section: sectionNumber) as IndexPath //scroll to bottom of current section
                            , at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.bottom, //right, left, top, bottom, centeredHorizontally, centeredVertically
                            animated: true)
```